# If Earth suddenly become a rogue planet what would humanity have to do to survive

Tags: humans, earth, survival

If Earth become a rogue planet leaving the sun's orbit and leaving our solar system what would humanity have to do to survive and how long could they survive?

Edit: I should note that it is not a sudden thing; people have a warning that it is happening.

Comment: If Earth became a _rouge_ planet, I imagine it'd be much like Mars.  Though possibly some sort of algal bloom, to change the colour of the seas.

Comment: That said, voting to close as duplicate, as there are _multiple_ "what if Earth didn't have a sun?" questions.

Comment: Note: we advise questioners to wait at least 48 hours before accepting an answer, as the international community here (many of whom may be asleep at the time of the question) may be put-off providing a better answer by that action. We ask you to consult the [help] regarding our ways.

Comment: The amount of energy required to tear Earth from it's orbit is quite likely, among the other minor side effects, to kill all life, boil away the oceans, and shatter the crust. Gotta survive the un-survivable first.

Comment: Had this Q not been closed as a duplicate, it would most likely have been closed anyway. The [help/dont-ask] states, "To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where … you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: 'What if ______ happened?'” We call questions like this a [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4868/40609) and they're usually closed. Please understand that the SE model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer and that it is not a discussion forum.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I see it you have basically two options. Migrate to Mars before you are too far away or move underground with fusion plants. Since you probably want to stay on earth I would suggest fusion plants.

Since the planet will become very cold you will need to create huge underground caverns. Deep enough underground it will become warm again so you don't need very much heating. More a heat distribution system to warm everything evenly with the heat coming from geothermal. For your food supply, you need huge underground farms with a lot of light. For the lights, you need a lot of power to simulate the sun. All other energy usages will be minor compared to the farm lights Although you could probably use geothermal power plants I would opt for fusion reactors, if your settings allow. Probably they are easier to maintain in the long run for the huge energy requirement than geothermal.

If you survive the initial year, your main focus would be developing farm plants or algae farms that require as little energy as possible and insolate every surface to keep as much heat inside the planet as possible. Later you will want to build colony ships since long-term stability is probably not viable.